# テキスト画面をコピーしてHTMLで表示したい

Tags: javascript, html, css

Linuxでコンソールアプリを実行した画面をコピーしてHTMLで表示したところ、綺麗に表示されません。
どうすれば綺麗に表示できるのでしょうか？

## 再現手順

Ubuntu20.04で以下のコードを実行して出てきた画面を、gnome-terminalの「HTMLとしてコピー」を使ってhtmlファイルとして保存します。

### テキストアプリ(bash)

```bash
selected=$(
    for i in `seq 50`;do
        echo "$i" "item$i"
    done |
    xargs whiptail --menu '選択して下さい' 20 40 12 3>&2 2>&1 1>&3)
```

### HTML

保存されたHTMLは以下のようになっています。

```html
<pre>

<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">┌──────────────────────────────────────┐</font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│ 選択して下さい                       │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             </font></span><span style="background-color:#CC0000"><font color="#D3D7CF">1  item1 </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">  ↑             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             2  item2   ▮             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             3  item3   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             4  item4   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             5  item5   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             6  item6   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             7  item7   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             8  item8   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             9  item9   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             10 item10  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             11 item11  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             12 item12  ↓             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│       &lt;了解&gt;         &lt;取消&gt;          │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">└──────────────────────────────────────┘</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                     </font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC">                                        </font></span>

</pre>
```

### Stackoverflowだと...

StackoverflowでHTMLをそのまま貼り付けるとこんな表示です。

```
                    ┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
                    │ 選択して下さい                       │ 
                    │                                      │ 
                    │             1  item1   ↑             │ 
                    │             2  item2   ▮             │ 
                    │             3  item3   ▒             │ 
                    │             4  item4   ▒             │ 
                    │             5  item5   ▒             │ 
                    │             6  item6   ▒             │ 
                    │             7  item7   ▒             │ 
                    │             8  item8   ▒             │ 
                    │             9  item9   ▒             │ 
                    │             10 item10  ▒             │ 
                    │             11 item11  ▒             │ 
                    │             12 item12  ↓             │ 
                    │                                      │ 
                    │                                      │ 
                    │       <了解>         <取消>          │ 
                    │                                      │ 
                    └──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

ここではプレビューで見る限り、スタイルが消える反面、フォントが適切に選択されており、保存されたファイルをブラウザで見るよりは見れる表示になっています。

### 原因調査

#### フォントと行間指定

すぐ分かるとおり、フォントと行間の指定がないので、先のHTMLに以下のコードを追記してみたのですが、改善はするものの綺麗とは言い難い状況です。

```html
<style>
pre {
line-height: 1.0;
font-family: "menlo","lucida console","consolas","courier new","courier",monospace;
}
</style>
<pre>

<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">┌──────────────────────────────────────┐</font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│ 選択して下さい                       │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             </font></span><span style="background-color:#CC0000"><font color="#D3D7CF">1  item1 </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">  ↑             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             2  item2   ▮             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             3  item3   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             4  item4   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             5  item5   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             6  item6   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             7  item7   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             8  item8   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             9  item9   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             10 item10  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             11 item11  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             12 item12  ↓             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│       &lt;了解&gt;         &lt;取消&gt;          │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">└──────────────────────────────────────┘</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                     </font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC">                                        </font></span>

</pre>
```

#### 複数の固定幅フォント

Windowsのメモ帳などで見ればすぐに分かりますが、複数のフォントが使用されていることが明白です。
確認用に以下のスクリプトをHTMLの後ろに追加しました。

```html
<style>
pre {
    line-height: 1.0;
    font-family: "menlo","lucida console","consolas","courier new","courier",monospace;
}
</style>
<pre>

<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">┌──────────────────────────────────────┐</font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│ 選択して下さい                       │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             </font></span><span style="background-color:#CC0000"><font color="#D3D7CF">1  item1 </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">  ↑             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             2  item2   ▮             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             3  item3   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             4  item4   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             5  item5   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             6  item6   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             7  item7   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             8  item8   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             9  item9   ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             10 item10  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             11 item11  ▒             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│             12 item12  ↓             │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│       &lt;了解&gt;         &lt;取消&gt;          │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">│                                      │</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                    </font></span><span style="background-color:#D3D7CF"><font color="#2E3436">└──────────────────────────────────────┘</font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC"> </font></span>
<span style="background-color:#75507B"><font color="#EEEEEC">                     </font></span><span style="background-color:#2E3436"><font color="#EEEEEC">                                        </font></span>

</pre>
<pre><span id="test"></span></pre>
<script>
(function(){ 
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const N = 1000;
const content = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;
const width = {};
[].forEach.call(content, (ch) => {
    if (width[ch] == null) {
        test.textContent = [...Array(N)].map(()=>ch).join('');
        width[ch] = test.offsetWidth / N;
        const codePoint = "0x" + ch.codePointAt(0).toString(16);
        console.log(`[${ch}(${codePoint})]: ${width[ch]}px`);
    }
});
})();
</script>
```

Windowsのchrome上でのコンソール出力は以下のとおりです。

```
[
(0xa)]: 0px
[ (0x20)]: 9.641px
[┌(0x250c)]: 9.641px
[─(0x2500)]: 9.641px
[┐(0x2510)]: 9.641px
[│(0x2502)]: 9.641px
[選(0x9078)]: 16px
[択(0x629e)]: 16px
[し(0x3057)]: 16px
[て(0x3066)]: 16px
[下(0x4e0b)]: 16px
[さ(0x3055)]: 16px
[い(0x3044)]: 16px
[1(0x31)]: 9.641px
[i(0x69)]: 9.641px
[t(0x74)]: 9.641px
[e(0x65)]: 9.641px
[m(0x6d)]: 9.641px
[↑(0x2191)]: 9.641px
[2(0x32)]: 9.641px
[▮(0x25ae)]: 8px
[3(0x33)]: 9.641px
[▒(0x2592)]: 9.641px
[4(0x34)]: 9.641px
[5(0x35)]: 9.641px
[6(0x36)]: 9.641px
[7(0x37)]: 9.641px
[8(0x38)]: 9.641px
[9(0x39)]: 9.641px
[0(0x30)]: 9.641px
[↓(0x2193)]: 9.641px
[<(0x3c)]: 9.641px
[了(0x4e86)]: 16px
[解(0x89e3)]: 16px
[>(0x3e)]: 9.641px
[取(0x53d6)]: 16px
[消(0x6d88)]: 16px
[└(0x2514)]: 9.641px
[┘(0x2518)]: 9.641px
```

#### 質問

複数の固定幅フォントに対してうまい幅指定方法、もしくはそれに準ずるうまい方法はないのでしょうか？
(罫線に使用されるフォントの幅を基準とした方法)
可能であればJavaScriptは使いたくありません(そこまでするなら画像にするかも)

##### 追記

私が対処できればそれでいいわけではなく、検索してここに来た方が必要な回答はJavaScriptでの回答なのかもしれません。一文字ずつspanにすることで対応可能な分野である以上、JavaScriptを外す選択肢はありえないので、ご理解ください。

##### 追記2

低評価したい方はコメントに具体的な指摘を同時にお願いします。仮に同じ内容でも無言では私怨にしか見えません。
「***適切な指摘***」なら対応しますよ。

Comment: それぞれブラウザ上での表示結果もあるとイメージが伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: 不要です。気になる人はどうせ自分で見るので。フォントセットやプラットフォームやブラウザによってかなり現象変わりますし。今後も変わり続けると思います。

Comment: 勝手にタグ外さないでもらえますか？コメントもないし気づくことすらありません。

Comment: 手元の環境で質問文のHTMLセクション内のhtmlをローカルに保存して、mozilla.orgからダウンロードしたFirefox107.0(フォントはHackGen Console NFJ)で表示したところ、上から2行目(選択してください)と下から4行目(<了解> <取消>)の右端の影である黒い箇所がm文字幅スペースとn文字幅スペースの差くらい飛び出して見えます。
これを綺麗でないので揃えたいということでしょうか？ それとも @dameo さんの環境ではそれ以外にも気に入らない箇所がありますか？　質問文冒頭の**綺麗に表示されません**を具体的にしてくださるとより回答が付きやすくなるように思います。

Comment: 不要です。原因調査の内容を読めばそれ以外には読めませんし、分からなければ回答も出来ません。内容を理解せずに回答されても困ります。

Comment: 「そこまでするなら画像にするかも」といありますが、その場合はgnome-teminalのスクリーンショットを貼り付けるという意味ですか？そういうことであれば、やりたいことは、各文字の色や配置、背景色などが、gnome-teminal上で表示さた時と同じになるものをHTML上で表示させたいと言うことであってますか？

Comment: 「テキストアプリ」とはテキストを扱うアプリという意味でVSCodeやvimと言った[テキストエディタ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%BF)の事ですか？それともテキストだけで表現されるアプリという意味でNetHackやvimと言った[コンソールアプリケーション](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3)の事ですか？

Comment: @raccy スクリーンショットを貼るという意味です。色や配色が重要だという意味ではありませんし、そこは問題視していません。むしろ(見た目が崩れて)綺麗でないこと以外に何を問題視していると解釈したのか分かりません。

Comment: gnome-terminalの表示は目標の基準にはならないと言うことであってますか？私のブラウザ環境では質問の最初のHTMLはgnome-terminalと同じように表示されますが、dameoさんの回答のものは行と行の間に白いラインが入ってgnome-terminalの時とは異なる表示になります。なので、理想はgnome-terminalの時と同じなのか違うのかだけでも聞きたかったのです。せめて、「そこまでするなら画像にするかも」とした場合の画像を提示して頂けませんか？

Comment: 明確な目標は必要ありません。HTMLのレンダリング上問題となる部分が適切なコスト内の変更でいろいろな環境で少なくなればいいだけです。私が確認した範囲はWindows/Linux/AndroidのChrome/Firefoxだけですよ。画像は不要です。問題があるのなら原因を調査・説明した上で、必要なら環境の開示をお願いします。

Comment: 明確な基準も示してくれず、理想となる画像の表示も拒否されるのであれば、「質問が明確では無い」としてクローズ票を入れざるを得ません。。第三者がどうしたらいいのか明確にわかるように質問を編集してください。

Comment: 必要がない理由は説明しましたが。。。それは私が決めることではありません。

Comment: あらら、明確な理由もなく私怨クローズですか・・・誰のために何をした結果なんでしょうね。クローズすることによるメリットがどこにあるのか、よく考えた方がいいですよ。

Comment: ここはあなたのためのサイトではなく良質なQ&Aの蓄積することを目的としたサイトです。その実現方法は [マイナス投票する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) とそのリンク先 [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) で説明されていますが、 **maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers.** 回答者を最大限に優遇するとともに、**keep question quality high, even at the cost of refusing a little sand.** 質の低い質問を排除する方針です。過去の質問もそうですが、個人的な主張ばかり行う dameo さんの行動は閲覧者や回答者に嫌悪感を与える有害な質問と判断しクローズに投じました。今の方針を継続されるのであればSOjaでなくご自身のblogなどに投稿してください。

Comment: 嫌悪感や個人的感情で、技術的価値のある質問をクローズするとは読めませんけど。。。主張を行っているのはお互い様というか、言い掛かりをつけてるのは回答者さんだけですよ。普通に回答可能な質問です。自分の言う事を聞かない人に制裁をしたいだけにしか見えません。仮にあなたが何かをしなかったとして誰かが困るのでしょうか？誰も困る人はおらず、技術的な課題が解決せずに終わるだけの話です。分かりきったことを説明させないでください。

Answer (score 1):

## 回答

以下のWebフォントを指定して固定幅を合わせる。
https://number-shot.net/blog/illusion-the-console-terminal-font/

### 詳細

以下をダウンロードして展開し、webfontフォルダにHTMLを配置する。
https://github.com/tomonic-x/Illusion/releases/download/v0.2.5/Illusion-0.2.5.zip

配置したHTMLファイルのStyle要素を以下のように修正してブラウザで表示する。

```html
<link href="./Illusion.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
pre {
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-family: "Illusion N", monospace;
}
</style>
```

### 最後に

完全に目的に適合したフォントが運良く見つかった感じです。固定幅と言いながら幅の違うフォントがいくつもあったり、East Asian Widthとやらに絶望したりしましたが、他に方法がなければしばらくこれで行こうかと思います。